# CSS Radio Button issues

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm putting together a simple form to deposit a set amount of money. The form has 4 radio buttons.

`<form action="deposit.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" name="deposit" value="100"> $100
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="deposit" value="250"> $250
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="deposit" value="500"> $500
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="deposit" value="1000"> $1,000
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Deposit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>`

Here is the output:
[image]

You can see that the last radio button is not vertically aligned. I realize that there are 2 extra characters in the text after the button. I'm no CSS wizard and haven't really found the answer to making these buttons straight. Any ideas?

EDIT: CSS code here:

```
.container {
    /* center contents */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    width: 20px;
}
```

The form is in the container

Comment: I copy pasted the code from your question and ran it and it seems to be perfectly aligned. Run your code without your CSS file and see what happens.

Comment: hmm thats strange. I'll give it a shot. The only thing i could think is that `<div class="form-group">` could be causing an issue. this is part of a problem that requires me to link my files to bootstrap and the form-group class could be overwriting my other css. I could also be way off and that might not have anything to do with it at all lol

Comment: Check my answer below. it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file or within your HTML code you are using the "align centre" setting. Thats why is not aligned.

This is the output of your above code with the align centre setting:

[image]

And this is the output of your code without the align centre setting:

[image]

Somewhere in your code you are setting the below div class to align centre.

```
 // Removing the align setting will solve the issue. If its not in-line CSS then check you external CSS file.
 <div class="form-group" align="center">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my container group (where the radio buttons lie) contain css of `text-align: center;` but even overwriting that with css specifically for the radio buttons doesnt change the styling

Comment: would you mind posting your CSS in your question above?

Comment: just did. hope it provides more clarity. even taking out the `text-align: center` in the `.container` css didn't do anything. Sort of stumped now.

Comment: is this the only CSS you have connected to your HTML file or do you have any other external CSS files?

Comment: no this isn't but the rest of the css shouldnt have an impact. i can post it if youd like.

Comment: no I mean do are using external CSS files like bootstrap or anything. Something thats not written by you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use tables to make the buttons align (its easier with dreamweaver as your editing tool)